# what is 'calldepth' parameter for in logger.Output() method in log package?

Tags: go, logging, built-in

In document https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger.Output,

there is `calldepth` argument in `logger.Output()` method.

I played with example code in doucment and it seems like when I pass higher value, logger print out lower location logging event occured.

When I pass 1 as calldepth param, I understand `logger.Output()` script is written in exact line 15.

```
INFO: prog.go:15: Hello world
```

But when I pass 2, I got below.

```
INFO: prog.go:19: Hello world
```

Why line number is different even though file name is both `prog.go`?

Answer (score 0):

[As documented](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Output):

> Calldepth is the count of the number of frames to skip when computing the file name and line number if Llongfile or Lshortfile is set; a value of 1 will print the details for the caller of Output.